# Why do I have to use MySQL from terminal only?

Tags: mysql

I managed to install MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04 from the terminal. Everything went perfectly.

But why can't I access MySQL like any normal application, i.e., from the menu? The only way I can use it is from the terminal, which is quite uncomfortable. Is this the only way to use this application in Ubuntu? How can I open the normal MySQL window?

Comment: How did you install MySQL?

Comment: @ThomasWard I installed from the terminal, following this tutorial step by step: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Perhaps add a screenshot of "the normal MySQL window" to allow people to see what you mean?

Comment: Because MySQL is a database server. It's not a "normal application". If you want to connect to it with a local GUI application, then you need to install one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you've actually installed MySQL's command line client. If you were on Windows, you would have got MySQL command line client as an application which runs on top of Command prompt. MySQL's Windows installer gives you an option to register MySQL service. That's why you have a separate application for that. On Ubuntu, services are generally registered automatically.

If you're interested in some GUI clients, [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) is the official one.

Answer (score 3):

### Installing mySQL-workbench

I don't know why, but the mysql-workbench package is missing in Ubuntu 20.04.

However, you can easily install it from the main page:

- Download apt installer package and copy the m5sum

  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

  Click if you don't want to create an account on the bottom link "No thanks, just start my download."
- Check the m5sum and install it

  Install it from your download-directory

  ```
  sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
  ```
- Update and install

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community
  ```
- Start a mySQL party:

  ```
  mysql-workbench&
  ```

[image]

Comment: mysql-workbench hasn't been shipped in the repos for some time, *because* of the fact that MySQL has their own apt repos.

Comment: thanks for your comment Thomas. I also think it's best to install directly from mysql , without shipping via ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You installed the mysql database.  And that doesn't come with a gui by (linux) default.

But you may choose a front end for it. [See here](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) for more infos. This is just one "recommendation" from the makers of mysql. There are many more database frontends out there. Just enjoy the freedom of choosing.